# Не собирается Maven проект

Tags: java, maven

Не могу собрать проект. Что я делаю не так?

Есть два модуля **А** и **Б**, **А** зависит от **Б**.

Сделал для них общий `pom.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>QueryService</module>
        <module>lib</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**Проект Б**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>Client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
</project>
```

**Проект А**, у которого не загружается dependency

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>QueryService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>Client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>project</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Ошибка:

> `Coudn't resolve dependencies for project project: QueryService:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Coudn't find artifact project:lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 0):

У вас `QueryService` зависит от `lib`, а `lib` собирается позже. Поменяйте их местами в редакторе.